# On Screen Keyboard gui is not working

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, grid-layout, border-layout

I am making a trying to display a textarea at the top and Keyboard keys below it, but when I run this code, the whole thing is mixed. What am I doing wrong and how can I solve it? Here is the code:

```
public Keyboard()
{
    super("Typing Tutor");

    pane1= new JPanel();
    pane2= new JPanel();
    pane3= new JPanel();
    pane4= new JPanel();
    pane5= new JPanel();
    pane6= new JPanel();

    glayout= new GridLayout(5,14);
    text= new JTextArea(770,300);

    text.setFocusable(true);

    Handler = new HandlerClass();

    pane1.add(text);

    setLayout(glayout);

    but= new JButton[57];

    AssignLettersToButtons();

    text.addKeyListener(Handler);

    add(pane1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    add(pane2);
    add(pane3);
    add(pane4);
    add(pane5);
    add(pane6);

}

private void AssignLettersToButtons()
{       
    for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    {
        if(i<14)
        {
            but[i]=new JButton(names[i]);
            pane1.add(but[i]);
        }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Please attach some images which you are getting as output and place images which is your expected output.

Comment: I am unable to upload the image I need 10 reputation for that :P

Comment: You are having that reputation

Comment: I made your reputation, now thanks to me

Comment: There are different types of layouts. Try different layout like null layout(not sure but may be that will help you).

Comment: @Zara *"null layout(not sure but may be that will help you)"*  `null` layout causes (plague, pestilence &) misery.

Comment: @AndrewThompson yeah you are right , I think boxlayout will be perfect in your case  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: can I get a little help with code on how to arrange buttons in keyboard layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Design it may take at least 3 panels. As in following[image]

Comment: still not working. I did this 
pane2.setLayout(glayout);
  pane3.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10,20));
pane3.add(pane1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
  pane3.add(pane2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
  add(pane3);