# Setting layout in java using GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout, jbutton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [On Screen Keyboard gui is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428104/on-screen-keyboard-gui-is-not-working)

I am making a keyboard using Jbutton in java. The problem I am unable to set the layout of keyboard with layout of the original keyboard. How can I do this? I am learning java and I have been sitting to solve this problem for the last 3 hours and couldn't find a solution.Here is the code:

```
public Keyboard()
{
    super("Keyboard");

    pane1= new JPanel();
    pane2= new JPanel();
    pane3= new JPanel();

    glayout= new GridLayout(5,14,2,5);
    text= new JTextArea(15,65);


    text.setFocusable(true);

    Handler = new HandlerClass();

    pane1.add(text);

    pane2.setLayout(glayout);
    pane3.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5,5));

    but= new JButton[57];

    for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++)
    {
            but[i]=new JButton(names[i]);
            pane2.add(but[i]);
    }

    text.addKeyListener(Handler);

    pane3.add(pane1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    pane3.add(pane2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    add(pane3);

}
```

[image]

How can I solve this problem?

Regards

Comment: Why not update your question you posted 5hours ago ? Voting to close this an as a duplicate

Comment: If I am not getting response from there what would I do than? Sitting duck !

Comment: You could always wonder why you do not get any responses ... improve your question (for example with an [sscce](http://sscce.org)) and you will get responses. Just dumping the same information in a new question will only annoy people (and resulting in a closed question as a duplicate ;-) )

Comment: Robin If you have energy to vote for closing this question on the basis of duplicate, Why don't you put this energy in answering my other question

Comment: Simple. I cannot copy-paste the code you posted and run it as it won't compile.

Comment: Robin No reason to argue in comment section. if you can't be helpful than don't argue here please

Comment: What a keyboard layout do you want `AntiRSILayout`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer to my question myself. I just made panels for each row in keyboard. It is a lengthy way to solve this problem but It gets the job done. If any other person has better solution post it in answer and I will select that answer.